# How can I read user roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Currently I'm writing a TicketSystem in ASP.NET and have trouble with the Admin Panel.

I want read out the user roles and I'm getting the following error message:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: "'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'"

Code to read the user role:

```
 public  List<String> getRols(dynamic user)
    {

        return _UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user).ToList();
       
    }
```

Many Thanx for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access to add the `ToList` on a Task, which is something that doesn't exist. You either have to await the method, or take the result from the async call.

The best solution is the await solution, so it would be:

```cs
public async Task<List<string>> getRols(dynamic user)
{
    return await _UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
}
```

Comment: THX for the Help, but i have now another Error (‾◡◝)

Comment: @Hacknet What is the error you're having now?

Answer (score -1):

Are you missing a using directive for System.Linq?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer but sadly this was not the Problem (*^▽^*)